# How to delete row from both Datagridview and the record from the table

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, delete-row

In my datagridview, you can select a row, and upon pressing a button, the content of two of the four fields is transported to another table. At this point, the row selected in my datagridview should be deleted from both the datagridview and the table it's reading from. Currently I am able to take the two fields I need and put them into the other table, but am having difficulty deleting this record after.

This is my code:

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\..\RailwayDatabase2.accdb"  
        Dim Con As OleDb.OleDbConnection  
        Dim comm As OleDbCommand  
        Dim rowval As Integer  
        Dim connect, query As String  
        Try  
            rowval = RotorDGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex  
        Catch ex As Exception  
        End Try  

        Dim col1 As String  
        Dim col3 As Date  
        col1 = RotorDGV.Rows(rowval).Cells(1).Value  
        col3 = RotorDGV.Rows(rowval).Cells(3).Value  
        connect = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\..\RailwayDatabase2.accdb"  
        query = "INSERT INTO tbl_shifts (EmployeeName, ShiftDate) VALUES(""" & col1 & """,""" & col3 & """);"  
        Con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connect)  
        comm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, Con)  
        Con.Open()  
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The row I need deleted currently equals RotorDGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex or 'Rowval'.

Can someone please tell me how to erase this record from both the table and datagridview upon clicking this button. Thank you

Comment: delete from the table, then just refresh your grid. Please define "having difficulty". are you getting an error?

Comment: I just don't know how to code the deletion of the record

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Comment: If the DGV is bound to the DB deleting the row (by code or by user action) from the datagrid will delete the local copy of the record (Actually mark it for deletion.). You then need to call Update on the record source/tableadapter so it can perform the DB update.

Answer (score 0):

After you do the *insert statement* and *execute* the query.

Repeat the process for *delete staement* and *execute* the query again.And then *remove* a row from the *datagridview*.

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\..\RailwayDatabase2.accdb"  
        Dim Con As OleDb.OleDbConnection  
        Dim comm As OleDbCommand  
        Dim rowval As Integer  
        Dim connect, query As String  
        Dim col1 As String  
        Dim col3 As Date 


 Private Sub RotorDGV_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles RotorDGV.CellClick
        Try
            rowval= DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex  
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
  End Sub
```

In the button *click* event, do the following all code.

> 1. Insert statement

```
        col1 = RotorDGV.Rows(rowval).Cells(1).Value  
        col3 = RotorDGV.Rows(rowval).Cells(3).Value  
         query = "INSERT INTO tbl_shifts (EmployeeName, ShiftDate) VALUES(""" & col1 & """,""" & col3 & """);"  
        Con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)  
        comm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, Con)  
        Try
        Con.Open()  
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery() 
        Con.Close() 
        Catch ex As Exception
        Con.Close() 
        End Try
```

> 2. Delete statement

```
        query = "DELETE STAEMENT"
        Con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)  
        comm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, Con)  
        Try
        Con.Open()  
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery() 
        Con.Close() 
        Catch ex As Exception
        Con.Close() 
        End Try
```

> 3. Remove row from Datagridview

```
RotorDGV.Rows.RemoveAt(rowval)
```

Hope it helps or at least you get a hint.

Answer (score -1):

Can you run a stored procedure to delete ? I would pass in the parameters needed to delete the record.